# Проблема с выпадающим div

Tags: html, css

Необходимо сверстать 2 раскрывающихся `hover`'ом блока в двух рядах.

При наведении на верхние блоки, нижняя часть раскрывается, но не "настилается" на нижний блок (и, как я понимаю, попадает под него). `z-index` проблему не решает, т. к. контекстные группы разные.

Как реализовать полное перекрытие выпадающим блоком любых других? На `css` или `js`, не имеет значения.

Спасибо.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 240px;
  height: 170px;
  z-index: 3;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.item-open {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 165px;
  left: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 130px;
}
.item:hover {
  background: red;
}
.item:hover .item-open {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="" id="mydiv" class="item">
    <span>Блок 1</span>
    <div class="item-open"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="item">
    <span>Блок 2</span>
    <div class="item-open"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="item">
    <span>Блок 3</span>
    <div class="item-open"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="item">
    <span>Блок 4</span>
    <div class="item-open"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Уберите `z-index: 3;`.

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо!

Comment: Или самой .item:hover { background: red; z-index: 10; } тоже задавать z-index;

Answer (score 1):

Используйте обычный jQuery и метод toggle.

```js
var btn = $("#mydiv");
var cnt = $("#mydiv_content");

btn.click(function(){
 cnt.toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<div id='mydiv'>
Click me
</div>
<div id='mydiv_content' style="display: none">
Test
</div>
```

На сколько я помню, элементы созданные JS будут всегда иметь самый последний z-index.

Comment: Увы, работает только для клика и очевидно сдвинет нижний блок, но спасибо